# What is the difference between two ways of using delegates in C# (with new keyword and without)

Tags: c#, delegates

I wonder that there are two ways of using delegates in C#, with "new" keyword and without:

```
delegate void D(string value);    
static void Main()
{
    D d1 = new D(v => Console.WriteLine(v));  // 1
    D d2 =       v => Console.WriteLine(v);   // 2
    d1.Invoke("cat");
    d2.Invoke("cat");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Is there any difference?

P.S.
I noticed that visual studio form designer generates code with "new" keyword (for events), but when I remove it (from generated code), it works either:

```
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        this.button1.Click += this.button1_Click;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any difference?

No.  Both forms compile to the exact same IL.

> P.S. I noticed that visual studio form designer generates code with "new" keyword (for events)

In older versions of C#, explicitly instantiating the delegate was required.  C# 2 added [delegate inference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163970.aspx#S10), which allows you to assign a method group to a delegate (or use with an event) directly.  The designers still choose the original form, which was required prior to C# 2.0, but is still valid.

Comment: Syntactic sugar as they say

Comment: Interesting. I accept your answer. But still I wonder why they shoose original form. And also I wonder what is the logic of using "new" keyword in this construction. I meen, what if I use same instance of delegate many times? Do I really need to create instance each time with "new" keyword?...

Comment: @Astronavigator If you actually create the delegate, you can assign it multiple times.  You don't need the "new" keyword every time.

Comment: @Astronavigator Because Visual Studio still needs to work with C# 1.0 and the alternative is worse.  You could maintain two separate code-gen tools for absolutely no gain