# Can't remove methods from delegate object invocation list properly

Tags: c#, delegates

As I read here and there a little, adding to or removing methods from the invocation list with or without the `new` keyword of a delegate object in C# is exactly the same and produces the same IL. See this one for example: [What is the difference between two ways of using delegates in C# (with new keyword and without)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942953/what-is-the-difference-between-two-ways-of-using-delegates-in-c-sharp-with-new) that had this fragment of code:

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
this.button1.Click += this.button1_Click;
```

No difference between those two. But I accidentally came across observing the unusual output with this code when I used `delegate` for passing as method parameter:

```
private delegate void TextPrinter(string text);
private static TextPrinter _handler;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TextPrinter myPrinter = PushMessage;
    RegisterHandler(PushMessage);
    UnRegisterHandler(PushMessage);
    InvokePrinter("hello");
}

private static void RegisterHandler(TextPrinter methods)
{
    _handler += methods;
}

private static void UnRegisterHandler(TextPrinter methods)
{
    /* first routine >> */_handler -= new TextPrinter(methods);
    /* second routine >> */ //_handler -= methods;
}

private static void InvokePrinter(string message)
{
    _handler(message);
}

private static void PushMessage(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine("# :: {0}", message);
}
```

If I use the second routine in `UnRegisterHandler`, everything works as how it should. But when I use the first one, the `PushMessage` method won't be removed from the invocation list of `_handler` although that with or without `new` I guess it must have worked properly. So, what is the issue here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got two different syntaxes here:

- `DelegateType x = new DelegateType(MethodName)`
- `DelegateType x = new DelegateType(ExistingDelegateInstance)`

Those do different things - the first builds a new delegate instance based on a *method group conversion*. That's entirely equivalent to just:

```
DelegateType x = MethodName;
```

The second builds a new delegate instance which is effectively "redirected" to the existing instance, and isn't equal to it. This is easily demonstrated:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {        
        Action action1 = Main;
        Action action2 = new Action(Main);
        Action action3 = new Action(action1);

        Console.WriteLine(action1.Equals(action2)); // True
        Console.WriteLine(action1.Equals(action3)); // False
    }
}
```

It's very rarely a good idea to create a new delegate instance which refers to another one, unless it's for the sake of delegate variance - which is also better handled than it used to be via reference conversions (there's a reference conversion from `Action<string>` to `Action<object>` for example, with no loss of identity).

Comment: "which is also better handled than it used to be" - Was `Action<T>` not always contravariant?

Comment: @dcastro: Nope - not until .NET 4.0. Theoretically I believe it *could* have been in that the CLR already supported generic variance, but I don't believe the relevant attributes were ever applied within the standard libraries.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've just tested out the `Equals` method in `UnRegisterHandler` as this: `Console.WriteLine("Equality: {0}", _handler.Equals(methods))`  but it returned `true` in contrast. Why?

Comment: @atoi.powered: Because it *is* equal to that - it's not equal to `new TextPrinter(methods))`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Let me explain with an illustration. I give some of your sample codes numbers in an order to refer to them later: (1) >> `Action action1 = Main;` (2) >> `Action action3 = new Action(action1);` (3) >> `Console.WriteLine(action1.Equals(action3)); // False`. Now, I think what happens in `UnRegisterHandler`'s parameter is: `TextPrinter methods = PushMessage;` which is exactly as number (1) of yours in case of semantics. `_handler -= new TextPrinter(methods); // exactly as (2)` and `Console.WriteLine("Equality: {0}", _handler.Equals(methods));` which is exactly as (3). Am I wrong?

Comment: @atoi.powered: No, your `_handler -=` is trying (and failing) to unsubscribe a handler. It's not clear how you can expect that to be equivalent to assigning a value to a new variable...